# Passing data from one ViewController to other in seque

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

What is wrong with below code. It is crashing with SIGABRT (unrecognized selector sent to instance)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",valueName);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushView"])
    {
    secondViewController *svc = (secondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    svc.passedName = valueName;
    }

}
```

The valueName iVar is an NSString which i want to pass.

Comment: post the crash details. and screen shot of storyboard where this seque is set.

Comment: Did you forget the `pushView` segue identifier ?

Comment: I have the segue identifier in place.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Don't forget to embed you `FirstViewController` with `NavigationController`

**2)** Don't forget to set your segue identifier.

[image]

**3)** Use the same code you have:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //for example if you value is "123"
    NSString *valueName = @"123";
    NSLog(@"%@",valueName);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushView"])
    {
        secondViewController *svc = (secondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        svc.passedName = valueName;
    }
}
```

**4)** Now, in your `secondViewController`, log you value in `ViewDidLoad`to see if it is passed...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"value: %@", self.passedName);
}
```

**5)** The result you should get:

[image]

Comment: I already did every step as you mentioned above. Since i am using Xcode 6 beta 5, the Push(now deprecated) segue has been changed to "Show". I wonder if it could be the problem.

Comment: No you error in not from the Xcode6 beta 5 being depreciated. You error is somewhere else. Check your connections. Did you delete something in the storyboard and did not delete the connection as well ?